# Variety on search result

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

First of all: Sorry for the long post, I am trying to explain a hard situation in an easy way and, at the same time, trying to give as much information as I can.

I have an algorithm that tries to determine user expectation during a search. There are a couple of way I can use it and I have the same problem with both of them, so, lets say I use it for disambiguation. Well, with a db structure like this one (or any other that allows the work):

**post**

```
ID | TITLE
---+----------------------------------------------
1  | Orange developed the first 7G phone
2  | Orange: the fruit of gods
3  | Theory of Colors: Orange
4  | How to prepare the perfect orange juice
```

**keywords**

```
ID | WORD     | ABOUT   
---+----------+---------
1  | orange   | company 
2  | orange   | fruit   
3  | orange   | color
```

**post_keywords**

```
ID | POST  | KEYWORD
---+-------+---------
1  |   1   |   1 
2  |   2   |   2
3  |   3   |   3
4  |   4   |   2
```

.

If in a search box, an user make a search for the word "orange", the algorithm would look that `orange` may refers to the company, the color, or the fruit and, by answering a couple of questions, it tries to determine which the user is looking for. After all that I get an array like this one:

```
$e = array(
    'fruit' => 0.153257,
    'color' => 0.182332,
    'company' => 0.428191,
);
```

In this point I know the user is probably looking for information about the fruit (because `fruit`'s value is closer to `0`) and if I am wrong my second bet goes for the `color`. At the bottom of the list, the `company`.

So, with a Join and `ORDER BY FIELD(keywords.id,  2,3,1)` I can give the results the (almost) perfect order:

```
- Orange: the fruit of gods
- How to prepare the perfect orange juice
- Theory of Colors: Orange
- Orange developed the first 7G phone
```

.

Well... as you can imagine, I wouldn't come for help if everything is so nice. So, the problem is that in is the previous example we have only 4 possible results, so, if the user really was looking for the `company` he can find this result in the 4th position and everything is okay. But... If we have 200 post about the fruit and 100 post about the color, the first post about the company come in the position 301st.

I am looking for a way to alternate the order (in a predictable and repeatable way) now that I know the user is must likely looking for the `fruit`, followed by the `color` and the company at the end. I want to be able to show a post about the `fruit` in the first position (and possibly the second), followed by a post about the `color`, followed by the `company` and start this cycle again until the results ends.

**Edit:** I'll be happy with a MySQL trick or with an idea to change the approach, but I can't accept third-party solutions.

Comment: I'd group by category in fact and return the best result for each category, and allow at this point  the user to then click the category to see all the other links for that category.

Comment: It looks like you're building an inverted index in MySQL with your keywords table. You have some query understanding capabilities. Have you thought about using Elasticsearch instead?

this talk of mine might help you wrap your head around how you'd use Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/opensource-connections-the-ghost-in-the-search-machine

Comment: ^ i agree.. ElasticSearch will be very helpful here.. That way you will be able to rank search results and a lot of other cool stuffs related with searching...

Comment: @Eric I can't use that options, cuz I didn't explain exactly what I am doing because is a bit more complex, so, I invented a situation more easy to explain (a blog example) but keeping the same principles. But, is enougth to say that into users' eyes, the kind of categorization we make is going to look rediculous, but, on the test of the algorithm they said "Now all the good information is together, must of the time on the fisrt page, but if I can't find it on page 1, I won't until page 20 or something".

Comment: @DougT. Yes, I use inverted index but I am going to read about Elasticsearch, and see how use full it can be.

Comment: @DougT. Elasticseach is not an option for me right now. I just need an idea to alternate the results as I asked on the question.

Comment: Just another idea. I see you use MySQL. Are you using 5.7? 5.7 full text natural search has been reworked based on Sphinx and it's pretty good. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to provide custom sort field.

```sql
SELECT
  p.*,
  CASE k.about
    WHEN 'company' THEN @sort_company := @sort_company + 1
    WHEN 'color' THEN @sort_color := @sort_color + 1
    WHEN 'fruit' THEN @sort_fruit := @sort_fruit + 1
    ELSE NULL
  END AS sort_order,
k.about
FROM post p
  JOIN post_keywords pk ON (p.id = pk.post)
  JOIN keywords k ON (pk.keyword = k.id)
  JOIN (SELECT @sort_fruit := 0, @sort_color := 0, @sort_company := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY sort_order, FIELD(k.id, 2, 3, 1)
```

Result will look like this:

```
| id | title                                   | sort_order | about   |
|---:|:----------------------------------------|-----------:|:--------|
|  2 | Orange: the fruit of gods               |          1 | fruit   |
|  3 | Theory of Colors: Orange                |          1 | color   |
|  1 | Orange developed the first 7G phone     |          1 | company |
|  4 | How to prepare the perfect orange juice |          2 | fruit   |
```

Comment: This one looks like it may works. I am not able to try it right now, but I am gonna try it in a couple of hours. =D

Comment: I just want to say: It worked. And I appreciate the simplicity of this solution. You're simply a genius.

Comment: Thanks :-) Nice to hear that it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do need some way of categorizing, or, I would prefer to say, clustering the answers. If you can do this, you can then start by showing the users the top scoring answer from each cluster. Hey, sometimes maximising diversity really is worth doing just for its own sake!

I think you should be able to cluster answers. You have some sort of scoring formula which tells you how good an answer a document is to a user query, perhaps based on a "bag of words" model. I suggest that you use this to tell how close one document is to another document by treating the other document as a query. If you do exactly this you might want to treat each document as a query with the other as an answer and average the two scores, so that the the score d(a, b) has the property that d(a, b) = d(b, a).

Now you have a score (unfortunately probably not a distance: that is, with a score, high values mean close together) and you need a clustering algorithm. Ideally you want a fast one, but maybe it just has to be fast enough to be faster than a human reading through the answers.

One fast clustering algorithm is to keep track of N (for some parameter N) cluster centres. Initialise these to the first N documents retrieved, then consider every other document one at a time. At each stage you are trying to reduce the maximum score found between any two documents in the cluster centre (which amounts to getting the documents as far apart as possible). When you consider a new document, compute the score between that document and each of the N current cluster centres. If the maximum of these scores is less than the current maximum score between the N current cluster centres, then this document is further away from the cluster centres than they are from each other so you want it. Swap it with one of the N cluster centres - whichever one makes that maximum score between the new N cluster centres the least.

This isn't a perfect clustering algorithm - for one thing, the result depends on the order in which documents are presented, which is a bad sign. It is, however, reasonably fast for small N, and it has one nice property: if you you have k <=N clusters, and (switching from scores to distances) every distance within a cluster is smaller than every distance between two points from different clusters, then the N cluster centres at the end will include at least one point from each of the k clusters. The first time you see a member of a cluster you haven't seen before, it will become a cluster centre, and you will never reduce the number of cluster centers held, because you would be ejecting a point which in a different cluster from the other centres, which won't increase the minimum distance between any two points held as cluster centres (reduce the maximum score between any two such points).